# Visual Studio 2017 - After upgrade from .Net Framework 4.52 to 4.61 unable to update service references

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2017

I have a Winforms application which uses WCF service (also part of the solution) I am using the Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Framework 4.52 and everything was working fine. I upgraded the project to .Net Framework 4.61 (all projects in current solution including WCF project) after the upgrade I am unable to update service reference in WinForms project and keep getting below error

> The current project does not support service references. To enable windows communication foundation support, change the target version of the Microsoft .Net Framework

I trying restarting Visual Studio and my machine but still no luck. I can assure that there is no error in any of the projects because if I downgrade project back to .Net Framework 4.52 then I am able to update service reference successfully so something Visual Studio don't like about 4.61!

Comment: Is the problem solved? If my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer. If the problem is not solved, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce your problem but no success.You can use svcutil to generate proxy classes,svcutil is a .NET tool that retrieves metadata from a web service on a network location or from a WSDL file, and generates a WCF class containing client proxy methods that access the web service operations.

You can use this tool on the command-line interface of VS:

[image]

Executing the above command will generate the a proxy class and configuration file on disk D.Then add these two files to your project:

[image]

**You can also try to add a new service reference and delete the original service reference.**

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with .Net 4.6 and after installing 4.6.2 the problem was resolved